# Mutability (?) of a list in python keyword argument

Tags: python, mutable, keyword-argument

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Least Astonishment” in Python: The Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-the-mutable-default-argument)

I am not sure what this is called, and thus have had difficulties finding documentation for what is going on. I was hoping someone here might be able to point me in the right direction.

In the following example, where I have a list as a default value for a keyword argument, it behaves in a way I was not expecting:

```
class A(object):
    def __init___(self, c=[0,0]):
        self.c = c

class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        super(B, self).__init__()

a = A()
b = B()

print a.c, b.c  # outputs [0, 0] [0, 0]

a.c[1] = 5

print a.c, b.c  # outputs [0, 5] [0, 5]
```

I understand that lists are mutable, but I had assumed that in the case of using a list as a default keyword argument, a 'new' list would be created each time. Is there documentation explaining why this is not the case?

Comment: related: [“Least Astonishment” in Python: The Mutable Default Argument](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-the-mutable-default-argument)

Comment: This should be closed as an exact duplicates. It is also one of the most common problems. See @PaoloMoretti 's comment for better answers on this topic.  This article probably explains it even better: http://effbot.org/zone/default-values.htm

Comment: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#a-word-about-names-and-objects

Comment: @PaoloMoretti -- perfect, that is exactly what I was after, thanks.

Comment: @KayZhu -- I agree this is a dup of Paolo's link -- how do I close?

Comment: @BrT You don't really need to do anything, we just need one more vote to close it from a user who can either vote or close :)

Answer (score 1):

Python creates a list that you specified as the default value once time, and then assigns it by reference. So:

```
>>> a1, a2 = A(), A()
>>> a1.c is a2.c
True
>>> a1.c.append(42)
>>> a2.c
[42]
```

Using this:

```
class A(object):
    def __init___(self, c=None):
        self.c = c if c is not None else [0, 0]
```

For more information read [this](http://effbot.org/zone/default-values.htm), and also you can see [this popular question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-the-mutable-default-argument).

Comment: Yes, this is how I fixed it, but I am interested in finding out the reason.

Comment: @BrT yes me too. All the explanations say "because it's mutable" but don't explain why mutability should lead to the sharing of the value in subsequent calls.